# How to avoid escaping when adding content to Nodes in Xerces?

Tags: java, encoding, xml-parsing, xerces

Can we add content containing html/xml tags to a Node in Xerces?

I have an empty `Node` with the name `<content>` to which I want to add the content
`Article <span class="old">13</span><span class="new">14</span>` for having the desired node like:

```
<content>
    Article <span class="old">13</span><span class="new">14</span>
<content>
```

If I use `setContent()`, it will escape the string and the result will be:

```
<content>
    Article &lt;span class="new"&gt;13&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class="old"&gt;14&lt;/span&gt;
<content>
```

**Is there a way to say Xerces to not html escape the string in input?**

The workaround I found is to wrap the desired content with a fake tag, create the node, and than copying the children to the target,

```
Node node = ...; "<content></content>"
String fakeNodeAsStr = "<fake>" + "Article <span class=\"old\">13</span><span class=\"new\">14</span>" + "</fake>";

DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(fakeNodeAsStr.getBytes(UTF_8));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
Node fakeNode = doc.getDocumentElement();
fakeNode = document.importNode(fakeNode, true);

NodeList nodeList = fakeNode.getChildNodes();
int length = nodeList.getLength();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Node child = nodeList.item(0); //always the first child
    node.appendChild(child);
}
```

But as you see is to much code and unnecessary delay (performance) for achieving such a basic request.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: There probably is no better way to do it.  How much of a performance hit does this incur?

Comment: In the range of 200-300ms with a file of 100 nodes. The computation's output is shown to a user. I would like to remove those seconds from the overall waiting time.